# Setting up page returned by controller action

Tags: apache, file, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

My problem is to make the server to recognize the files in my folder, I'm doing my own MVC framework and the problem comes about when I redirect a page from my controller, for example in the first time with an empty url and calling the Home controller like 
*`/MySite/`* it found all the images and files I need to show the page, for example:

*`/MySite/css/file.css`* or *`/Site/Image/image.jpeg`*,

because the server found the directories in the rewritten url `public/Image/image.jpeg`.

But if I make an url like *`/MySite/index/action`* and define another action to call
when the controller finally returns the page, and all the files in the page being loaded, it tries to found that files, but these urls come back to my front controller like
*`/MySite/index/css/file.css`*

I don't understand why the url is not overwitten at all, but the call for the file overrides only the last part, so the action, naturally the files found the first time in *`public/Image/image.jpeg`* cannot be found at *`public/index/Image/image.jpeg`*..

Can anyone help with this?

my .httpaccess files is realy simple:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$   public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the file inside public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\??(.*)$ index.php?route=$1&query=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i folloewd the following tutorial for make that : http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/ , seems not work at all..

Comment: for everyone that income in the same problem i found the solution, if your front controller get in a file you have to redirect it to the correct location with the header funzionality of php like header("Location: http://localhost/scripts/script.js");